# How I can add a picture as background in Android studio?

Tags: javascript, android, xml

How can I add a picture as background in Android studio?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is using an ImageView behind all your views(it is possible with framelayout) here is your xml:
(you may use a different scaleType)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:src="@mipmap/background"/>

            <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">



            <!-- put your views here -->




            </RelativeLayout>


</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Programmatically you can do like this. 
In different activities you can use the same layout file. 
Give a name to your layout : - myLayout
Define a variable for the layout.
Protected View myLayoutView;
Read the  layout as a view
myLayoutView = (View) findViewById (R.id.myLayout);
Then set background as follows:
myLayoutView.setBackground((Drawable) myBackground);

All the above you write in the onCreate method of your activity. You can change the background anytime.

There may be several other views in the layout which may be displaying their content on the screen there may be animations also but the background remains static behind all those.